# Trying to copy all occurrences of a string with in quotes to another file using grep

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a line in my file that has [LocString getString:@"some string"]; and i am trying to use grep so it copies all occurrences of some string to another text file. I know there are regex patterns for this but after googling i have had no luck. This is probably a simple problem which is why. Anyone know of a way to do this with either grep or sed? Thanks in advance as i am a newbie at this.

Comment: The `LocString getString` line occurs in the file once? And `some string` occurs multiple times in the rest of the file? And you want to output all the lines that contain `some string`? Could you provide a small sample of the input and desired output?

Comment: Anything beyond `grep -o '"[^"]*"' file`?

Comment: I dont understand why someone down voted this but to answer your question, this occurs more than once in a file, and i am trying to delete all the character except the string with in the double quotes and place the extracted string in to another file. I was trying to accomplish this with either grep or sed.Anyways i figured it out with help from tripleee, just had to use the -o flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/[^"]+"([^"]+)".*/\1/' original_file > new_file
```

Basically the `s` command like `s/search/replace/` replaces a searched pattern by a replacement. The search pattern works like this:

`[^"]+` matches one or more characters not equal to `"` - the part before the opening `"`. The `"` matches the opening `"`. The pattern between the parentheses `(...)` introduces a sub pattern, we'll access this value later in the replacement. `[^"]+` matches a sequence of one or more characters not equal to `"` - the value between the quotes. Finally we match the closing `"` plus any remaining character until the end of the line.

In the replacement pattern we are using the contents of sub pattern 1, the value between the quotes which has been matched by the search pattern.

---

If you are limited to basic regular expressions, meaning `-r` doesn't work, you can use this:

```
sed 's/[^"]\+"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/' original_file > new_file
```

Comment: Thanks ill try it and see what happens.

Comment: i tried it and it was giving an error sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: based on that this is what i am using though its still not working sed -r 's/[^"]+"([^"]+)".*/\1/' EventItem.m > all-strings.txt

Comment: You are using a MAC? Then you are limited to basic regular expressions, let me add that